# Remove duplicate endpoints in springdoc for "slashed" and "not slashed" URLs

Tags: spring, rest, springdoc

In new spring versions trailing slash URI matching configuration has been removed. So now I use it like

```
@GetMapping({"/", ""})
```

But as a result, I observe duplicated endpoints everywhere, like in Idea IDE and springdoc generated OpenAPI definitions. It is formally correct because there are actually two URIs, but is there a way to make it more logical by "exposing" just one, either with or without trailing slash?